# How to filter for files that starts with numbers [0-9]

Tags: powershell

i have a powershell script that copies files from one folder to the next.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "\\source" -filter "1*.835" | select Name,CreationTime

foreach ($f in $files){
if (-Not (Test-Path -Path "G:\destination\$($f.name)") -and -Not (Test-Path -Path 
"G:\destination\$($f.name)") -and $f.CreationTime -ge  "4/24/2019"){
Copy-Item -Path "\\source\$($f.Name)" -Destination 'G:\835'
}}
$filenames = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'


$files = Get-ChildItem "G:\835" -Filter '*.835' | select Name
```

I need to change:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "\\source" -filter "1*.835" | select Name,CreationTime
```

To something like this:

```
 $files = Get-ChildItem "\\source\*.835" | ? { $_.Name -match "[0- 9]*.835" } | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt "12/21/2019" -and $_.CreationTime -lt "01/02/2020"} | select Name,CreationTime
```

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out i changed it to:

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem "\\source\[0-9]*.835" | select Name,CreationTime
```